# Expectation of $C|D$ if we know $P(S)$ and $P(C|S)$ and $P(D|S)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given if we know $P(S)$ and $P(C|S)$ and $P(D|S)$, how do you compute $E[C|D=d]$? One way that I thought of is to find the conditional probability of $P(C|D)$ by computing the joint probability $P(C,D,S)$ and marginalizing it over $S$. But, $P(D|S)$ is a binomial distribution with parameter $q$ and $S$. Finding the full joint probability distribution will be too complicated. Does anyone know an easier way to find $E[C|D=d]$? Thanks.

Note: I forgot to mention that C and D are independent given S

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
P(C\cap S)=P(S)P(C|S), P(D\cap S)=P(S)P(D|S)
$$
This information is not enough to let you compute 
$$
P(C\cap D), P(C|D)
$$
because you lost information at
$$
P(C\cap D\cap S^{c})
$$
and in principle you do not know what this is.

Answer (score 0):

$$
E(C\mid D=d)=\frac{E(C;D=d)}{P(D=d)}
$$
$$
E(C;D=d)=\sum_{c,s}c\,P(C=c\mid S=s)\,P(D=d\mid S=s)\,P(S=s)
$$
$$
P(D=d)=\sum_{s}P(D=d\mid S=s)\,P(S=s)
$$